# Alternate voltage regulation for a linear power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I'm building a linear power supply. The first stages are all working great. Coming out of the rectifier and filter caps, I have 28V DC. I also have a voltage reference circuit (LM317) that gives me a stable 14V.

Here's a schematic of what I have so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyrdlR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I now want to add the regulation circuit for the output transistors. Similar to a power supply I built before, I was just going to use an op amp to drive the output transistors (probably through a high current buffer) so the output voltage matches the reference voltage. I also had a transistor for current limiting, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVy6M7.png)</sup>

However, that would require me powering the op amp off of 28V (under no load), and the most any of the op amps I have can handle is 22V supply. I'm figuring I can't run the op amp off of the 14V line since its output will likely need to be higher than 14V to drive the output transistor.

I could buy other op amps, but I'm curious if I can get by with what I have.

I know I could just make a step down circuit to power the op amp, but I'm thinking there has to be a more elegant solution. Is there a more elegant/better solution?

Comment: Why not use your 14V to power the opamp?

Comment: byl, can you show the power supply you built before? And how much current compliance are you considering?

Comment: @periblepsis what do you mean by current compliance?

Comment: How much output current do you need? And what power transistor do you want to use?

Comment: @byl What Jonathan just asked -- `current compliance` just means `what's the maximum current that might be required of the supply?`

Comment: What op-amps do you have available? (The schematic says LM741, but maybe that was left as a default value.)

Comment: @TimWilliams I have 741s, 272s, and 5532s.

Comment: @periblepsis gotcha. I need 4-5 amps out.

Comment: @JonathanS. I haven't settled on an output transistor yet, but will probably use two or three in parallel. I have plenty of power FETs, but I'm not too familiar with how to use those. Would the schematic change much between using FETs versus BJTs on the output?

Comment: 5532 is rated for plenty of voltage; notice the rating is bipolar, the total is double or 44V.

Comment: @TimWilliams ah, I hadn't realized that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconsider a derived power supply for the opamp.  If the Power Q is a darlington, the opamp needs only 5 to 10 mA of operating and output current.  This can be done with 1 zener diode, 1 resistor, and 1 noise filter capacitor.  50 cents?  You don't show a power supply decoupling capacitor for the opamp, but it already should be a part of the control schematic.

Comment: I hadn't realized the current draw would be so low. A zener diode would be easy then...